# Spring MVC not picking static resources mentioned in html files

Tags: java, spring, angular

I am developing a simple Spring MVC(v4.1.2) and Angular4 app.

Basically this app does CRUD operations by making http requests from angular client.

Following combination works perfectly fine:
Angular app ran using "ng serv"
Spring MVC war deployed in a application server.

Now, I am trying to combine both the client and server into a single project. With this I should be able to generate a single war file containg both client and server side code.

For this,

- copied `dist` of angular app into `..src/main/webapp/`. 
  [image]
- overridden following methods of `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  public class ServletContextConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.favorParameter(false).favorPathExtension(true).ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
              .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
              .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.enable();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/dist/");
  }
  ```

  }
- Changed **`web.xml`** as following:

  ```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  ```

After deploying and running the app, I get following errors in the web console:

[image]

**`index.html`**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>StoreClientApp</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script 
     type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script 
     type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script 
     type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script 
     type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

    </html>
```

---

It is evident from the console logs that Spring is triggering http requests for the static resources in `index.html`. Is this expected behaviour? What should be the changes so that Spring considers static resources as actually static and fetches them from relative path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context path is `/store-server` and the requests to your static resources are to the root. You can do one of the following to fix it

- Update the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/store-server">`
- Deploy your spring war at the root context path(/)
- Update the path of the individual script/css to point to
  /store-server/{resource-name}

Comment: Perfect! I didn't wanted to make client code tightly coupled on server for context path details. I think second solution will ensure one time change and client can freely include relative paths for static resources. Thanks!

Comment: For weblogic users: Setting  <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root> in weblogic.xml will set the context root to /.

Answer (score 2):

http://127.0.0.1:7001/inline.bundle.js It hasn't contextPath, so you need correct it.

http://127.0.0.1:7001/store-server/inline.bundle.js

1.static definition

```
<base href="/store-server">
```

2.dynamic definition

If you use pure HTML, you can get contextPath by the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contextPath = "/"+window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
    document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + "<base href='" + contextPath + "' />";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html Try to add a forward slash to each one of the URLs of the script file being used . Like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/inline.bundle.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script
 type="text/javascript" src="/styles.bundle.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="/main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```